# yum "Transaction Check Error" pointing to files that do not exist

Tags: yum, rpm

I am trying to install a boost148 package. This is a separate package from the boost, which I have installed and is version 1.41.

```
yum install boost
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Install Process
Package boost-1.41.0-18.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

But when I try to install Boost148 using `yum install boost148 -y` I receive the following

```
Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/lib64/libboost_chrono-mt.so.1.48.0 from install of boost148-chrono-1.48.0-7.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package boost-chrono-1.48.0-14.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/libboost_chrono.so.1.48.0 from install of boost148-chrono-1.48.0-7.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package boost-chrono-1.48.0-14.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/libboost_date_time-mt.so.1.48.0 from install of boost148-date-time-1.48.0-7.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package boost-date-time-1.48.0-14.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/libboost_date_time.so.1.48.0 from install of boost148-date-time-1.48.0-7.el6.x86_64 conflicts with file from package boost-date-time-1.48.0-14.el6.x86_64
```

So I checked to see if boost148 is partially installed

```
yum list installed | grep boost148
```

Nothing Shows up.

Also if I try to ls any of the files in the transaction check error, they do not exist.

```
# ls /usr/lib64/libboost_chrono-mt.so.1.48.0
ls: cannot access /usr/lib64/libboost_chrono-mt.so.1.48.0: No such file or directory
```

I figure it is some type of yum database problem so I did a `yum-complete-transaction` and a `yum clean all` but I am still unable to install the boost145 package. Any ideas on how I can convince yum to proceed with the install?

#### Information Requested in Comments

@ bangal

`$yum repolist all
Loaded plugins: refresh-packagekit, security
repo id                repo name                                    status
adobe-linux-i386       Adobe Systems Incorporated                   enabled:      2
elrepo                 ELRepo.org Community Enterprise Linux Reposi enabled:    304
elrepo-extras          ELRepo.org Community Enterprise Linux Extras disabled
elrepo-kernel          ELRepo.org Community Enterprise Linux Kernel disabled
elrepo-testing         ELRepo.org Community Enterprise Linux Testin disabled
epel                   Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_ enabled: 11,750
epel-debuginfo         Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_ disabled
epel-source            Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_ disabled
epel-testing           Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - Test disabled
epel-testing-debuginfo Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - Test disabled
epel-testing-source    Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - Test disabled
rpmforge               RHEL 6.5 - RPMforge.net - dag                enabled:  4,718
rpmforge-extras        RHEL 6.5 - RPMforge.net - extras             disabled
rpmforge-testing       RHEL 6.5 - RPMforge.net - testing            disabled
sl                     Scientific Linux 6.5 - x86_64                enabled:  6,524
sl-debuginfo           Scientific Linux Debuginfo                   enabled: 10,255
sl-fastbugs            Scientific Linux 6.5 - x86_64 - fastbug upda enabled:  1,016
sl-security            Scientific Linux 6.5 - x86_64 - security upd enabled:  2,377
sl-source              Scientific Linux 6.5 - Source                disabled
sl-testing             Scientific Linux Testing - x86_64            disabled
sl-testing-source      Scientific Linux Testing - Source            disabled
repolist: 36,946`

@Michael Hampton

```
rpm -qi boost-chrono
Name        : boost-chrono                 Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : 1.48.0                            Vendor: (none)
Release     : 14.el6                        Build Date: Mon 03 Jun 2013 04:20:53 AM EDT
Install Date: Fri 06 Nov 2015 03:09:26 PM EST      Build Host: localhost
Group       : System Environment/Libraries   Source RPM: boost-1.48.0-14.el6.src.rpm
Size        : 628796                           License: Boost and MIT and Python
Signature   : RSA/SHA1, Mon 03 Jun 2013 05:01:38 AM EDT, Key ID fcc2e6fe304dba4d
Packager    : .sroycode
URL         : http://www.boost.org
Summary     : Run-Time component of boost chrono library
Description :

Run-Time support for Boost.Chrono, a set of useful time utilities.
```

Comment: There can be a problem with repository. What is the ouput of `yum repolist all`?

Comment: @bangal I added the output to the question, I don't see how it is useful though when `yum list installed | grep boost148` comes up empty.

Comment: Please check `rpm -qi boost-chrono`.

Comment: I suspect there are conflicting versions of the packages are available in different repos. You may verify this using: `repoquery -i boost148`. If that is the case, you can disable the repo and see.

Comment: @bangal epel is the only repository shown in the `repoquery -i boost148` results. Their are 2 entries one fo x86_64 and the other for i686

Comment: Can you also check it for package `boost148-chrono` and `boost148-date-time`?

Comment: @MichaelHampton The result of the rpm -qi make it look like boost48 was recently partially installed. Does this mean it was installed outside of yum?

Comment: @bangal `boost148-chrono` and `boost148-date-time` are both only in epel.

Comment: That `boost-chrono` 1.4.8 is a third party package, that came from somewhere other than the repos you have installed. Get rid of it and `boost-date-time` and your problem should clear up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually do have a couple of conflicting packages on your system: `boost-chrono` and `boost-date-time` provided by `.sroycode` (whoever he is). I have no idea how these got on your system, as .sroycode's repo doesn't seem to be in the list of installed repositories.

To resolve the problem, get rid of these packages, then try your installation again.

```
yum remove boost-chrono-1.48.0-14.el6.x86_64 boost-date-time-1.48.0-14.el6.x86_64
```

(If this shows additional packages to be removed, then you may get some idea of why they're present to begin with.)

Comment: I think that is close but not quite right, I get `Setting up Remove Process
No Match for argument: boost-chrono4
No Match for argument: boost-date-time-1.48.0-14
No Packages marked for removal` I think I need to find the actually rpm from .sroycode

Comment: Try copying and pasting. I see typos there.

Comment: nope `# yum remove boost-chrono-1.48.0-14 boost-date-time-1.48.0-14`copy and pasted. The typo was actually from me copy and pasting the results. I found what might be the rpm on http://sourceforge.net/projects/sroycoderhelrpm/files/SRPMS/ and am downloading it now.

Comment: Why are you downloading it? The point is that you need to _uninstall_ them!

Comment: I agree it sounds stupid to download something you want removed. My thinking is that yum doesn't know anything about the package, so it can't uninstall it. But if i download the rpm and use `rpm -e` it should "uninstall it".  Probably wrong

Comment: `rpm -e` might work, but it uses package _names_, not the actual packages.

Comment: both `yum remove` and `rpm -e` worked but the package name needed  `.el6.x86_64` at the end. I edited your answer to reflect that. Once the edit is approved I will accept the answer.